# Conjoining NOT IN with ANDs in WHERE clause of SQL QUERY inconsistancy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

Here's my debacle. If I run:

```
SELECT pnumber, count(distinct ssn) as  num_emps,nvl(sum(hours),0) as thours, nvl(sum(hours*salary/2000),0) as tcost 
   FROM project 
    LEFT JOIN (works_on join (employee 
    LEFT JOIN Department on DNO=DNUMBER) on essn=ssn) 
   ON pnumber=pno 
GROUP BY pnumber 
ORDER BY pnumber
```

I get

```
 PNUMBER   NUM_EMPS     THOURS      TCOST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          4       67.5     1027.5
     2          3       37.5      562.5
     3          2         50        960
    10          3         55      762.5
    20          3         25      522.5
    30          4         60      967.5
    40          0          0          0
    50          0          0          0
    60          0          0          0
```

When I run:

```
SELECT pnumber, count(distinct ssn) as  num_emps,nvl(sum(hours),0) as thours, nvl(sum(hours*salary/2000),0) as tcost 
   FROM project 
    LEFT JOIN (works_on join (employee 
        LEFT JOIN Department on DNO=DNUMBER) on essn=ssn) 
    ON pnumber=pno 
WHERE  ssn IN (select MGRSSN from DEPARTMENT)
GROUP BY pnumber 
ORDER BY pnumber
```

I get

```
 PNUMBER   NUM_EMPS     THOURS      TCOST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1          5        100
     2          1         10        200
     3          1         10        200
    10          1         10        200
    20          3         25      522.5
    30          2         25        530
```

Good so far, lets try this:

```
SELECT pnumber, count(distinct ssn) as  num_emps,nvl(sum(hours),0) as thours, nvl(sum(hours*salary/2000),0) as tcost 
   FROM project 
    LEFT JOIN (works_on join (employee 
        LEFT JOIN Department on DNO=DNUMBER) on essn=ssn) 
    ON pnumber=pno 
WHERE  ssn IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE) AND ssn NOT IN (select MGRSSN from DEPARTMENT)
GROUP BY pnumber 
ORDER BY pnumber
```

I get:

```
 PNUMBER   NUM_EMPS     THOURS      TCOST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1       32.5      487.5
     2          1        7.5      112.5
```

Also good, but when I try this (all i did was add another Not in the Where clause):

```
SELECT pnumber, count(distinct ssn) as  num_emps,nvl(sum(hours),0) as thours, nvl(sum(hours*salary/2000),0) as tcost 
   FROM project 
   LEFT JOIN (works_on join (employee 
       LEFT JOIN Department on DNO=DNUMBER) on essn=ssn) 
   ON pnumber=pno 
WHERE  ssn NOT IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE) AND ssn NOT IN (select MGRSSN from DEPARTMENT)
GROUP BY pnumber 
ORDER BY pnumber
```

I get "no rows selected"! How? There should still be 2 employees that are not managers or supervisors for pnumber 1. Please help? Thanks,

**EDIT**

Here is the result with just one NOT IN:

```
SQL> SELECT pnumber, count(distinct ssn) as  num_emps,nvl(sum(hours),0) as thours, nvl(sum(hours*salary/2000),0) as tcost
  2     FROM project
  3     LEFT JOIN (works_on join (employee
  4         LEFT JOIN Department on DNO=DNUMBER) on essn=ssn)
  5     ON pnumber=pno
  6  WHERE ssn NOT IN (select MGRSSN from DEPARTMENT)
  7  GROUP BY pnumber
  8  ORDER BY pnumber;

PNUMBER   NUM_EMPS     THOURS      TCOST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          3       62.5      927.5
     2          2       27.5      362.5
     3          1         40        760
    10          2         45      562.5
    30          2         35      437.5
```

Comment: The last but one query fetches two rows because of your IN clause ssn IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE) but the last query doesnt because your have changed it to NOT IN. Can you try to run your last but one query without the ssn IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE) condition. It should show you the reason.

Comment: PNUMBER   NUM_EMPS     THOURS      TCOST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3       62.5      927.5
         2          2       27.5      362.5
         3          1         40        760
        10          2         45      562.5
        30          2         35      437.5

Comment: Lemmme edit it on the original post

Comment: Done, so whats the solution?

Comment: Okay, your edited query gives NUM_EMPS = 3 for just this NOT IN clause, whereas your ssn IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE) condition gives the NUM_EMPS = 1. So what is the ssn for the other two? Is it NULL ?

Comment: Nope not null, in the first query you see count(distinct ssn) which doesn't take nulls, and you can see the result is 4. 1 is a manager and 1 is a supervisor. There are 2 left and they're not showing up in the query before the edit

Comment: From what you're showing here, it shud display the two rows but cant really tell without looking at the data :|

Comment: Actually, there were nulls. It is now resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` returns no rows where any value is `NULL`.  So:

```
WHERE ssn NOT IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE)
```

will filter everything out if even one row as `SUPERSSN` as `NULL`.  Here are two ways to fix it:

```
WHERE ssn NOT IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE where SUPERSSN is not null)
```

or:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from EMPLOYEE e where e.SUPERSSN = ssn)
```

(You might need an alias on the `ssn`, but I have no idea what table it comes from.)  In other words, the semantics of `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` are different when there is a `NULL` value.  `NOT EXISTS` (in my opinion) has the more intuitive behavior.

Now, why does this never return true if one of the values is `NULL`?

```
WHERE ssn NOT IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE)
```

If `ssn` is in the list of `SUPERSSN`, then it returns false.  That is easy.  If `ssn` is not in the list *and* none of the values are `NULL`, then it returns true.  That is easy.

If `ssn` is in the list and one of the values of `SUPERSSN` is `NULL`, then there's a conundrum.  Is `ssn` equal to the `NULL` value or not.  Well, *neither*.  Comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`.  And, `NULL` is treated as "not true" in `WHERE` clauses.  In short, if `SUPERSSN` has a `NULL` value, the expression can only return false or `NULL` -- and everything gets filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

WHERE  ssn NOT IN (select SUPERSSN from EMPLOYEE union select MGRSSN from DEPARTMENT)